# Using a sublist to retrieve data from a larger list

Tags: python, list

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975573) with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6975582/211563):

```
search = 'a'
[item[1] for item in data if item[0] == search]
['x']
```

I modified it to extract all information associated with the search item:

```
[item[1:] for item in data if item[0] == 'aa90_273024']
returns - [('F5XKBWO01AQCVH', 'F5XKBWO01AQCVH')]
```

Original list entry: `[...('aa90_273024', 'F5XKBWO01AQCVH', 'F5XKBWO01AQCVH')...]`

However, I need to do this with a list of several 1000s of search items as a sublist. How should I modify the code to retrieve all search items from the larger list, preferably to a `open("result.txt",'w').write()`

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you change the data format? What's being represented by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but here is a solution for what I've understood:

```
searches = ('aa90_273024', 'another_search', 'yet_another_search')
my_result = [item[1:] for item in data if item[0] in searches]
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but it kept returning len(my_result)=0.You answer made me go back and look at the search list and it still had additional '\n' that seemed to be confusing the search. Now it works. Thanks - glad it was simple.